How can I use value from the list as an index in z3 python SMT solver

this is the math formulation that I'm trying to recreate in Z3 SMT solver with python. My problem accrues on f_x_i
x = [Int(f"x{i}") for i in range(n)]
for i in range(0, n):
constraints.append(And(x[i] >= 0, x[i] <= m))

constraints.append(f_values[x[i]] >= e_values[i])

this the code that I'm trying to run and this is the error that I get:
onstraints.append(f_values[x[i]] >= e_values[i])
                   ~~~~~~~~^^^^^^
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not ArithRef

How can I get the value of x[i] and use it as an index?
